# Social Media Icons Not Rendering Properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When I visit a website by typing it into the address bar, my social media icons look like this:

[image]

However, when I refresh the page, they render properly. Unsure what is causing this or if the icons need to be compressed:

[image]

Also kind of odd, when I type the web address in the search bar and go to the site, I get the "Not Secure" warning in the upper left, however when I refresh the page it is indeed secure and the icons are loading properly. Perhaps it has something to do with typing the address in directly?

Comment: Does that happens with the incognito mode ? If not that might be related to your Adblock or Adguard extensions.

Comment: No it is the regular chrome browser, it happens in other browsers as well

Comment: Looks like you aren't waiting for the images to load before you try to display them.

Comment: This is lacking the information needed to give a specific answer - in this case, the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be the code that powers those icons. This could be any number of things - one likely culprit is using an icon web font (big clue is the "tofu" showing up) with a bad combo of caching + loading rules, so that (for some reason) the font is not being pulled correctly from cache, a problem solved by reloading & bypassing cache. That is why it is important to check if this also happens in incognito, or if you completely wipe local cache.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my website was not set up for forced https://, which was the root of the issue. My hosting provider was able to resolve.